# Translation: Human Penis (Traditional Chinese Medicine)

Tags: translation

According to Wikipedia's [List Of Traditional Chinese Medicines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_traditional_Chinese_medicines):

> Human penis
>
> According to Li Shizhen:

```
the human penis is not a drug
—[8]
```

> Human penis is believed under TCM to stop bleeding, and as with other TCM medicines, the basis for belief in its therapeutic effects is anecdotal and not based on the scientific method; Li Shizhen, author of the greatest pharmacological work in pre-modern China, the Bencao Gangmu materia medica, objected to use of human penis, but cited the anecdotal evidence and included it in the Bencao Gangmu, which is still a standard reference today.[8][26]

- Apparently human penis is listed in the *Bencao Gangmu*, what is the original text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

欽定四庫全書本《本草綱目》卷五十二 (*Bencao Gangmu*, vol. 52)

[image: Page89]
[image: Page90]

Answer (score 2):

**人势**

From an online [excerpt](http://zhongyibaodian.com/bcgm/renshi-2.html):

> （《纲目》）
>
> 【释名】阴茎。时珍曰︰人阴茎，非药物也。陶九成《辍耕录》载︰杭州沈生犯奸事露，引刀自割其势，流血经月不合。或令寻所割势，捣粉酒服，不数日而愈。观此则下蚕室者，不可不知此法也。故附于此云。
>
> 【主治】下蚕室，创口不合（时珍）。

Comment: Have to say this: may have been good for the patient, but sure wasn't good for the 'donor'!! Ouch!